# Can't stop the particles from overshooting

Tags: actionscript-3, simulation, physics, particle-system

I am trying to create a simple particle simulation. There are two types of particles static and moving. Static particles attract moving particles towards their centre. Static particles have a strength attribute which dictates how hard they are pulling the moving particles

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(moving.y - static.y , moving.x - static.x);
var dist = Point.distance(new Point(moving.x,moving.y) , new Point(static.x,static.y));

moving.velX += Math.cos(angle + Math.PI) * static.strength / dist;
moving.velY += Math.sin(angle + Math.PI) * static.strength / dist;
```

The problem is a when a particle is just passing through the centre the distance is very small that results in very large velocity values.

I added an extra check for distance before calculating velocity.

```
if (dist < 1)
    dist = 1;
```

But the problem still persists. I cant figure out the problem.

Here is a snapshot of an overshoot happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal force fields use square of distance as modifier, you here use single power of distance, of course the force field performs differently. You should change the `var dist` line to the following:

```
var dist:Number = (moving.x-static.x)*(moving.x-static.x) + (moving.y-static.y)*(moving.y-static.y);
```

This way `dist` will hold square of actual distance, so dividing by `dist` would give you the proper force field configuration.

And, please rename `static`, as it's a reserved word in AS3.

Comment: I have not used 'static' as a variable name in my original code.

Comment: @SayamQazi, check your code, you have `static.x` & `static.y`. Call it `force`, call it `atttractor` or whatever just not variable or Class names that change to same color as reserved words.

Comment: Yes I know. I was talking about my original code. I did not copy paste my original code here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably declaring that `dist` value before running the `dist` calculation or after running the `vel` calculation. Instead, make sure that the dist check you are doing is between the `dist` calculation and the `vel` calculation. Vesper is correct as well, in that to get the correct force effect, it should use the distance squared. But even doing that, you can still get undesirable (although completely accurate, mathematically) results.

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(moving.y - static.y , moving.x - static.x);
var dist = Point.distance(new Point(moving.x,moving.y) , new Point(static.x,static.y));

if (dist < 1) dist = 1; // just make sure your constraint goes here.

moving.velX += Math.cos(angle + Math.PI) * static.strength / dist / dist; // this uses dist squared
moving.velY += Math.sin(angle + Math.PI) * static.strength / dist / dist; // but don't use this method in addition to Vesper's or you'll have dist to the power of 4.
```

Comment: Yes I have the distance check in between the distance calculation and updating velocity part. You are saying that I may still get undesired results, so can you please propose me a solution.

Comment: Apparently Vesper solved your problem. You can just ignore my advice. Or did his solution not work?